# How to insert records in MySQL so can be received chronologically

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-9, laravel-10

I need to be able to retrieve a set of logs in chronological order of creation date & time. The order is important as value of new rows is dependent on the values of the latest inserted rows.

Here is an example table:

- id (unisgned int, PK, autoincrements)
- item_id (Foreign key)
- stock_change (int)
- current_stock_amount (int)
- created_at (datetime)

Example data may look like:

| id | item_id | stock_change | current_stock_amount | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 52 | 9850 | 5 | 5 | 2000-01-01 10:00:00 |
| 52 | 9850 | 10 | 15 | 2000-01-01 10:00:01 |
| 52 | 9850 | -2 | 13 | 2000-01-01 10:00:02 |

The easiest way to do this is use the `created_at` column:

```
select * from inventory_logs order by created_at desc
```

However, the issue is that some logs could arrive at the same second.

We could increase the precision to microseconds, but it is still possible for logs to be inserted in the same microsecond (although less likely).

The alternative approach is use some sort of incrementing id. Unfortunately, we cannot use the `id` column as the the number generated can be out of sequence.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What tie-breaker criteria can you introduce? Insertion order? If so, `ORDER BY created_at, id`. Why can't you use `id` if it's set to auto-increment? Manually inserting ID values is how you create a world of hurt for yourself.

Comment: if you have two records attempting to be inserted at the same microsecond or even close to that, there's no guarantee the earlier one will manage to get an incrementing id first; there is too much possibility of variable overhead changing the order of inserts.  if the actual events causing the inserts have some determined order, you need to somehow capture and use that.  if (more likely) they do not, really all you should worry about is being able to read a consistent order, and using a created at time and breaking ties using the id is good enough.

Comment: do make sure you set created_at in utc, not some time in a timezone with daylight savings

Comment: When MySQL receives the data to be saved then it does not know this data relative posession on the timeline. If there exists some (external) code place where this relative posession is known then the data must be expanded with according posession data in this code. Without this additional data your task seems to be non-solvable.

Comment: @tadman There shouldn't be any ties, as no 2 logs can possibly be inserted at the exact same time. Also a log is dependent on the last added log.